# BufferedinputStream default buffer size

Tags: java

BufferedinputStream default buffer size is 8k for my jvm.
Is that a harcoded value, or can it be changed by altering some system parameter?

I'd like it to use 128k without modifying the java code.
Is that possible?

Thanks,

Comment: No, there is no system property to change that

Comment: BufferedInputStream has a constructor where you can set your 128k buffersize

Comment: @KErlandsson Thanks! I was suspecting that, but asked just in case.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks, but that will cause me to change code!

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nice documentation! Not sure how it answers the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the default buffer size by a system property. You must use the constructor which accepts a `size` argument. The only place the buffer is created is in this constructor:

```
public BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size) {
    super(in);
    if (size <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    }
    buf = new byte[size];
}
```

This applies for my JVM version (1.8.0_31) but it could possibly be different on other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

It's not your `JVM`, but `Java` defines the default value of `8K` for the `BufferedInputStream`.

You can't change it from outside, without modifying your `java` program.

To modify from `Java`, you need to pass the SIZE in `Stream` constructor.

`new BufferedInputStream(file, size * 1024);` where size can be 128 for 128KB.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the  [BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size)](http://ulibgcj.sourceforge.net/javadoc/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#BufferedInputStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20int%29) constructor. But don't change it unless it is very necessary.